# Dhar's Burning Test - Confusion about Abelian Sandpile Model

Tags: abstract-algebra, statistics, graph-theory, physics

Dhar's Burning test is a bijection between the spanning trees of a certain graph and the recurrent states [Abelian sandpile model](http://theory.tifr.res.in/~ddhar/leuven.pdf).  I would like some help working out this bijection in different cases:

#### Square graph

One we pick a root there are 4 spanning trees:

```
o-o  o-o  o-o  o o  o-o
| |  |      |  | |    |
x-o  x-o  x-o  x-p  x-o
```

Also the recurrent states should be $\mathbb{Z}^3/V\mathbb{Z}^3$  where $V$ is the lattice $\mathbb{Z}(-2,1,0) + \mathbb{Z}(1,-2,1) + \mathbb{Z}(0,1,-2)$.  There should be 4 such states since:

$$ \left| \begin{array}{ccc} -2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \end{array}\right| = 4$$

How do I write down explicit 
representatives of $\mathbb{Z}^3/V\mathbb{Z}^3$ ? 
And how do we exhibit the Dhar bijection between the sandpile states and spanning trees in this case?

---

I got a list of stable configurations by drawing all marking the root with `x` and writing down all the possible configurations

```
1-0  1-1  0-1  1-1
| |  | |  | |  | |
x-1  x-0  x-1  x-1
```

My question is how do we match these configuations with the spanning trees above?